# How to represent interface implementation in proto file

Tags: protocol-buffers, protobuf-net

I am using protogen tool to generate c# classes from .proto files. I was wondering whether there is a possibility to represent interface implementation in a proto file. For example, is there any way to represent below in proto file.

```
interface ILog
{

}

class ConsoleLog: ILog
{

}
```

Answer (score 1):

.proto has no concept of interfaces, unless you count services (which protogen doesn't touch, anyway).

The code is all C# if you wanted to add something locally, however my advice would be to simply use "partial classes" for this, and add all the interface aspects in another code file. Protogen always emits partial classes.

Comment: Thanks for a quick answer. I will give it a try.

Comment: There were some ideas to do interfaces, but everything ended up in Messages being encapsulated inn other messages. This creates chaos if there are 20+ messages which are interleaved.

Comment: @MarkoBencik the current protogen never emits interfaces; interfaces aren't a concept that .proto deals in; protobuf-net has some limited support for serializing data *through* interfaces, but it sounds like you're making the classic mistake of trying to serialize your domain model, rather than creating a DTO model that is a good fit for the target serialization platform

Comment: To be fair I'm not working actively with protobuf-net, I'm working with C++ but this should not make a big difference. Now DTO are a thing of interpretation and most people do it wrong. I'm no sure that I have the same understanding as you. I think you mean the class decomposition model, if yes look at he lik. 
https://github.com/OpenSimulationInterface/open-simulation-interface/blob/master/osi_sensorview.proto
This is with what I am working with. Here you will see the domain model pulled into protobuf.

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR - Create an event wrapper

This is a bit late, but thought I would post an idea. It is not a use case for creating an interface on the .proto file - just a solution to a problem that I had which I felt is related to this post (I had the same initial idea). I wanted to process generic events, but the events are tied to the proto generated classes.

TempEvent.proto

```
message TempEvent {
    int32 deviceId = 1;
    float humidity = 2;
    float temperature = 3;
}
```

Consumer class taking from an event queue (sensor readings):

```
Service service;

TempEvent event = queue.remove();
((EventService)service).process(new EventWrapper(event));
```

Once the data is de-serialized, just create a simple wrapper which implements Event.

```
public interface Event<T> {
    T getEvent();
}
```

```
public class EventWrapper<T> implements Event {
    private T event;

    public EventWrapper(T eventType) {
        this.event = eventType;
    }

    public T getEvent() {
        return this.event;
    }
}
```